# API call using python to Azure DevOps to get list of users in an organization

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to make a simple api call using Python to Azure DevOps to get list of users. URL is providing results via browser but getting error while scripting as below. I need to further proceed with the json response. Can some one help please?
Python version: 3.8.3

**Script**

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get('https://vssps.dev.azure.com/siva*****/_apis/graph/users')
print(response)
print(response.json())

**Output:**
<Response [203]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Documents/github/terraform/azure-aks-kubernetes-masterclass/25-Azure-DevOps-Terraform-Azure-AKS/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json      
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
```

Comment: This seems like an authentication issue. You haven't authenticated so the URL will redirect to a login page. That is just HTML. What does line 4 print?

Comment: @JarroVGIT Thank you.  as you pointed out, authentication is the issue. It is solved now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 203 error is Authentication error when you running the Rest API.

You could use PAT([Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)) as the Authentication method.

You could grant **Graph Read** scope to the PAT.

[image]

Here is the Python example:

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

response = requests.get(
    url="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1", headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I have accepted the given answer